# Avoid identical client ajax request on refresh

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, duplicates

I would like to test if the ajax request is identical so it can be aborted or some other alert action taken?

In reality clients can change the request via a few form elements then hit the refresh button.

I have made a poor attempt at catching the identical request. Need to keep the timer refresh functionality.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    var current_request_id = 0;
    var currentRequest = null;
    var lastSuccessfulRequest = null;

    function refreshTable() {
        $('#select').html('Loading');
        window.clearTimeout(timer);

        //MY CATCH FOR DUPLICATE REQUEST NEEDS WORK
        if (lastSuccessfulRequest == currentRequest)
        {
            //currentRequest.abort();
            alert('Duplicate query submitted. Please update query before resubmission.');
        }

        var data = {   
            "hide_blanks": $("#hide_blanks").prop('checked'),
            "hide_disabled": $("#hide_disabled").prop('checked'),
        };

        json_data = JSON.stringify(data);

        current_request_id++;
        currentRequest = $.ajax({
            url: "/calendar_table",
            method: "POST",
            data: {'data': json_data},
            request_id: current_request_id,
            beforeSend : function(){
                if(currentRequest != null) {
                    currentRequest.abort();
                }
            },
            success: function(response) {
                if (this.request_id == current_request_id) {
                    $("#job_table").html(response);
                    $("#error_panel").hide();
                    setFixedTableHeader();
                }
            },
            error: function(xhr) {
                if (this.request_id == current_request_id) {
                    $("#error_panel").show().html("Error " + xhr.status + ": " + xhr.statusText + "<br/>" + xhr.responseText.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, "<br/>"));
                }
            },
            complete: function(response) {
                if (this.request_id == current_request_id) {
                    $("#select").html("Refresh");
                    window.clearTimeout(timer);
                    stopRefreshTable();
                    window.refreshTableTimer = window.setTimeout(refreshTable, 10000);

                    lastSuccessfulRequest = currentRequest;
                }
            }
        });
    }




    //TIMER STUFF TO refreshTable()
    //THIS SECTION WORKS FINE
    var startDate = new Date();
    var endDate = new Date();
    var timer = new Date();
    function startRefreshTable() {
        if(!window.refreshTableTimer) {
            window.refreshTableTimer = window.setTimeout(refreshTable, 0);
        }
    }
    function stopRefreshTable() {
        if(window.refreshTableTimer) {
            self.clearTimeout(window.refreshTableTimer);
        }
        window.refreshTableTimer = null;
    }
    function resetActive(){ 
        clearTimeout(activityTimeout);
        activityTimeout = setTimeout(inActive, 300000);
        startRefreshTable();
    }

    function inActive(){
        stopRefreshTable();
    }
    var activityTimeout = setTimeout(inActive, 300000);
    $(document).bind('mousemove click keypress', function(){resetActive()});

</script>


<input type="checkbox" name="hide_disabled" id="hide_disabled" onchange="refreshTable()">Hide disabled task<br>
<br><br>
<button id="select" type="button" onclick="refreshTable();">Refresh</button>
```

Comment: " is identical"...identical to what, precisely? The previous request? Any previous request? Something else? And identical in what sense? From the same user? The exact same parameters? Same headers? Please clarify your precise requirements. The way you're doing it now is naive. $.ajax returns a Deferred object, which you can't really compare for "equality" in any meaningful way with another one, and also tells you nothing about the contents of the request - it's designed for you to add callbacks to in order to handle the response. Once you clarify what you mean we can find a better way to do it

Comment: Also a side note: jQuery's `.bind` was superseded by `.on` way back in jQuery 1.7, and is now deprecated entirely. There should be no reason to still be using it, or worse, to use it for new code. http://api.jquery.com/bind/

Comment: Surely there is a way to make your point without posting a hundred lines of code. Read and follow [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the power of [.ajaxSend](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxsend/) and [.ajaxSuccess](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/) global handlers.

We'll use ajaxSuccess to store a cache and ajaxSend will try to read it first, if it succeeds it will trigger the success handler of the request immediately, and abort the request that is about to be done. Else it will let it be...

```
var ajax_cache = {};
function cache_key(settings){
    //Produce a unique key from settings object;
    return settings.url+'///'+JSON.encode(settings.data);
}
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function(event,xhr,settings,data){
    ajax_cache[cache_key(settings)] = {data:data};
    // Store other useful properties like current timestamp to be able to prune old cache maybe?
});
$(document.ajaxSend(function(event,xhr,settings){
    if(ajax_cache[cache_key(settings)]){
        //Add checks for cache age maybe? 
        //Add check for nocache setting to be able to override it?
        xhr.abort();
        settings.success(ajax_cache[cache_key(settings)].data);
    }
});
```

What I've demonstrated here is a very naïve but functional approach to your problem. This has the benefit to make this work for every ajax calls you may have, without having to change them. You'd need to build up on this to consider failures, and to make sure that the abortion of the request from a cache hit is not getting dispatched to abort handlers.

Answer (score 0):

One valid option here is to `JSON.Stringify()` the objects and compare the strings. If the objects are identical the resulting serialised strings should be identical.

There may be edge cases causing slight differences if you use an already JSONified string directly from the response so you'll have to double check by testing.

Additionally, if you're trying to figure out how to persist it across page loads use `localStorage.setItem("lastSuccessfulRequest", lastSuccessfulRequest)` and `localStorage.getItem("lastSuccessfulRequest")`. (If not, let me know and I'll remove this.)